# Svelte and Leaflet plugins not importing correctly

Tags: leaflet, svelte, sveltekit, leaflet.markercluster

I want to add various plugins to leaflet, such as: leaflet.markercluster.
On the internet I found an example to make leaflet work on svelte and I noticed that leaflet is imported via an asynchronous function.

This is my Map.svelte component:

```html
<script>
    import { onMount, onDestroy } from 'svelte';
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';

    let mapElement;
    let map;
    let markers = [
        { lat: 51.5, lng: -0.09, popupText: 'a' },
        { lat: 51.51, lng: -0.1, popupText: 'b' },

    ];

    onMount(async () => {
        if (browser) {
            const leaflet = await import('leaflet');
            await import('leaflet.markercluster');

            map = leaflet.map(mapElement).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

            leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);

            // Create marker cluster group
            const markerClusterGroup = leaflet.markerClusterGroup();
            
            // Loop through the markers array and create individual markers
            markers.forEach(marker => {
                const { lat, lng, popupText } = marker;
                const individualMarker = leaflet.marker([lat, lng]).bindPopup(popupText);
                markerClusterGroup.addLayer(individualMarker);
            });

            // Add the cluster group to the map
            map.addLayer(markerClusterGroup);
        }
    });

    onDestroy(async () => {
        if (map) {
            console.log('Unloading Leaflet map.');
            map.remove();
        }
    });
</script>


<main>
    <div bind:this={mapElement}></div>
</main>

<style>
    @import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
    @import 'leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css';
    @import 'leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css';
    main div {
        height: 800px;
    }
</style>
```

When I try to do the same thing with leaflet.markercluster it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I tried inserting the {#await} block but it doesn't change anything.
Now the +page.svelt

```html
<script>
    import Map from "./Map.svelte";
</script>

<h1>Mappona</h1>
{#await Map}
    Loading...
{:then Map}
    <Map />
{/await}
```

Error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: leaflet.markerClusterGroup is not a function
at Map.svelte:25:48

Comment: Can you share the error, if any you get with this code. alternatively, you could use the {#await} component to load the Map asynchronously within the html, just like here; https://svelte.dev/repl/079c14630f0a4c3785d7e83f58558075?version=3.16.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just importing `await import('leaflet.markercluster');`, you should give it a name:
`const markercluster = await import('leaflet.markercluster');`

and try to instantiate directly the `MarkerClusterGroup` class:
`const markerClusterGroup = new markercluster.MarkerClusterGroup();`

I should check why it doesn't add the `markerClusterGroup()` function to `leaflet`, but this is a good temporary solution.

[image]

If you check the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/bd2794c35831612a86f63766c26d94f809de7abc/src/MarkerClusterGroup.js#L1402), the function is just a proxy for the constructor, you can just use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if that's of any use, I was also having trouble with the dynamic imports I had to do the following:

```
const L = await import('leaflet');
await import('leaflet.markercluster');
```

and then I had to use the `window` variable to create the market cluster group:

```
const groups = window.L.markerClusterGroup();
```

that way I got it working. Note I am using Angular but I am executing that piece of code only in the browser.

Package versions:

```
"leaflet": "^1.9.4",
"leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",

"@types/leaflet": "1.9.8",
"@types/leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.4",
```

Hope that helps too.